# Writing a parser with Wisent

Tags: parsing, emacs, elisp, org-mode, cedet

I've described a grammar in a .wy file, but how can I build the parser?

Also, sorry if this question is too simple, but I'm having a bad time figuring out how to use CEDET. Are there any docs besides the gentle intro and the info files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the major mode for a grammar file, the keybinding `C-c C-c` will compile the grammar.  Use `C-h m` to describe any major mode to learn more about how to do things.  Also check the menu.

If you want to automate the build, you can use EDE to create a project of type Make, and add a grammar target to the project.  It will create a Makefile that can build grammars via Make.